# PS Perm Gen in ApacheTomcat is 98% when starting

Tags: apache, tomcat, permgen

The PS Perm Gen in Apache Tomcat occupies nearly 97%(80.7MB out of 82MB space allocated) as soon as the server is started. In course of time, the server goes down with Out Of Memory Error.

Is this normal ? or the value has to be less at the start and gradually increases? What should be done to avoid this? Can someone please explain . Thanks in advance :)

Comment: that's way too less than mine, which takes around 300-500 when starting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that sounds perfectly normal for a large web application.

The solution is to increase the size of the Perm Gen.

The problem is that your application needs to load more classes that you have space to load. Therefore you have to allocate more space in the Perm Gen to enable these classes to load. How much space will depend on your app. I'd start at 128M and double it until the application is stable.